# How can I set text value dynamically in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I want to set a text `value` by taking a `value` from another `page` or another input area. Here is my text field. I tried many combinations for `this.byId("thisOne").`, but they didn't work.

```
 this.byId("thisOne").setValue("Some thing");
```

another way:

```
  sap.ui.getCore().byId("thisOne")....
```

The text element:

```
<Text text="" id ="thisOne"/>
```

My XML file:

```
<mvc:View
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="App.view.Take"
    xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
    xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form">
    <Page showHeader="false">
          <Label text="thisOne" />
          <Input text="" id="thisOne" />
          <Button type="Accept" text="Accept" ></Button>
          <Button type="Reject" text="Reject" ></Button>
   </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you specify an ID explicitly for a control, within an XML view, the actual ID will be prepended with the ID of the XML view, for example the Input control might have an actual ID of "`__xmlview0--thisOne`".

Best practice is to use the XML View's byId function to get the ID of a control contained within it. So for example in your controller attached to the view (`App.view.Take.controller.js` in your case) you could do this:

`this.getView().byId("thisOne").setValue("Some thing");`

Comment: If you have a text element with "text" property, you should use .setText("SomeThing") method instead. Otherwise, .setValue("") will throw " setValue is not a function" error or vice versa.

Comment: @qmarco How can I change value of Label dynamically ? I have added <Label class="homeHeader" id="homeHeaderText"  text="some Text" ></Label> as a label in vertical layout and  tried to get text value like var msg = this.getView().byId("homeHeaderText").getText(); but getting blank value and to set value tried this.getView().byId("homeHeaderText").setText(msg); but not working ...am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

**Note that `setValue` will NOT work.** 
`setValue` is not the supported method for `sap.m.Text` Control. `setValue` is supported for `sap.m.Input` (or any other control which inherit properties from [`sap.m.Inputbase`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.InputBase.html) )

```
var oValue = sap.ui.getCore().byId("inputId").getValue();
```

Then

`sap.ui.getCore().byId("thisOne").setText(oValue);`

Refer to [`sap.m.Text`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Text.html) and [`sap.m.Input`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Input.html) for more details.

Comment: Not working. It say `Cannot read property 'setText' of undefined`.

Comment: which control are you using? sap.m.Text? something else

Comment: I am using `<Text text="" id ="thisOne"/>` . in my xml file.

Comment: I want to know which is the default xmlns referring to.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to get your textfield and then add a value to it. You have to do this:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("thisOne").setValue("Some thing");
```

Comment: I am taking this console log.
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined`.

Comment: Using the global core "byId" method in this case is not acceptable, very rude way, moreover it won't work because the XML View prefixes all inner controls with own id. Down voted.